# How can I update state of node instead of overwriting it?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Yes I know, that we have a tool called "spiceweasel" for handling all this, but I'm really curious, how and why it works that way in chef.

Chef brings a nice idea to have a whole repository of your described environments, this idea is great, but nodes doesn't seems to work they way I expect.

So here's a situation: 
You have chef-server/workstation setup, and you have `bootstraped` and `provisioned` nodes in your cluster already. As you know, each node runs `chef-client`, in some interval, that I will define. So each node re-runs recipes on random interval, to check if nothing was chanced, if changes - it changes back.

So you have folder `nodes/` in your repository. And when you do `knife upload /nodes`, all nodes configuration must be **updated**, but now it **overwrites** the state of node completely. So why this is bad? Because, let's say I've edited node configuration file and I've uploaded it to chef-server, then node state resets until next `chef-client run` operation. I've got a cookbook/role which resides on another node, and it checks ip from a specific node (which owns specific role). There's a big chance, that when `chef-client run` will be performed on one of the nodes, it won't find an IP of another node, and whole cookbook will fail to run!

Maybe it's wrong to use node states in cookbook, but hey, it's all over the place.. so now would be nice to have an option, just to **UPDATE** state  of node, not to overwrite it.

So question is: Is it possible to update state of node, instead of destroying it?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a knife plugin which fetches an existing node object from the chef server, updates it with the local values and saves it again.

I use [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/meineerde/7580432) for some time now (originally by [Chris Gaffney](https://gist.github.com/3800934/d04dfc5eafa5a307c0a4d1f713591deffededb32)):

```
class NodeUpdateFromFile < ::Chef::Knife
  deps do
    require "chef/node"
    require "chef/json_compat"
    require "chef/knife/core/object_loader"
  end

  banner "knife node update from file FILE (options)"

  def loader
    @loader ||= ::Chef::Knife::Core::ObjectLoader.new(Chef::Node, ui)
  end

  def run
    update = loader.load_from("nodes", @name_args[0])
    begin
      node = ::Chef::Node.load(update.name)
    rescue Net::HTTPServerException
      ui.info("Could not load existing node #{update.name}, assuming new node.")
      node = ::Chef::Node.new
      node.name(update.name)
    end

    # Replace attributes, run_list, and chef_environment from the new node
    # definition. 
    node.normal_attrs   = update.normal_attrs
    node.override_attrs = update.override_attrs
    node.default_attrs  = update.default_attrs

    node.run_list.reset!(update.run_list)
    node.chef_environment(update.chef_environment)

    # Expand the run_list in case it has changed
    node.expand!
    node.save

    output(format_for_display(node)) if config[:print_after]

    ui.info("Updated Node #{update.name}!")
  end
end
```

Just put it into your chef repository in `.chef/plugins/knife/node_update_from_file.rb` and use the new command

```
knife node update from file my.node.json
```

instead of the old `knife node from file my.node.json`

Comment: this is actually brilliant!!! I've accept your answer if nothing will pop-up, I'm actually interested in reason of chef-server to behave like that. It's really nice that this can be in chef repo itself!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can save and update all normal/override/automatic attributes of node each time if you don't mind.

1. perform `knife node show your-node-name --format json -l > nodes/your-node-name.json` to dump all node attributes. Notice parameter `-l` means long output including normal, override and automatic attributes.
2. update it
3. perform `knife node from file nodes/your-node-name.json`

which means you do save and update all attributes all the time.

Comment: is there's any chance that node state will be changed, if nothing changed on a role and cookbook? if it's wont,then this is perfect solution :) and probably that plugin above does the same

Comment: @holms it simply dump all node attributes including normal, overrides and automatic, so yes, that's the node state. However, it usually takes 30KB per a single node, so it's not very efficient from operation perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Holger's answer was not suitable for my environment, using his plugin many autogenerated attributes were deleted in `node.default_attrs  = update.default_attrs`

So, my solution to the problem is iterate over the attributes in the updated node and add them to the node in the chefserver. The resultant code is:

```
class NodeUpdateFromFile < ::Chef::Knife
    deps do
    require "chef/node"
    require "chef/json_compat"
    require "chef/knife/core/object_loader"
  end

  banner "knife node update from file FILE (options)"

  def loader
    @loader ||= ::Chef::Knife::Core::ObjectLoader.new(Chef::Node, ui)
  end

  def run
    update = loader.load_from("nodes", @name_args[0])
    begin
      node = ::Chef::Node.load(update.name)
    rescue Net::HTTPServerException
      ui.info("Could not load existing node #{update.name}, assuming new node.")
      node = ::Chef::Node.new
      node.name(update.name)
    end

    # Replace attributes, run_list, and chef_environment from the new node
    # Note: With this appproach attributes will never be removed from the chefserver
    update.normal_attrs.each { |key, value| node.normal_attrs[key] = value  }
    update.override_attrs.each { |key, value| node.override_attrs[key] = value  }  
    update.default_attrs.each { |key, value| node.default_attrs[key] = value  }

    node.run_list.reset!(update.run_list)
    node.chef_environment(update.chef_environment)

    # Expand the run_list in case it has changed
    node.expand!
    node.save

    output(format_for_display(node)) if config[:print_after]

    ui.info("Updated Node #{update.name}!")
  end
end
```